# Reshape NxNxM array to MxNxN

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, reshape

I have an array of 25000 images with dimensions 128x128. I want it to have size 25000x128x128 instead of 128x128x25000. Reshaping it in Matlab:

```
data_reshaped = reshape(data, 25000, 128, 128)
```

where `data` has dimensions 128x128x25000. However, when I try to visualize one of the images in `data_reshaped` with `imshow(squeeze(data_reshaped(1,:,:)))`, I get a *corrupted* image.

[image]

Comment: you want to `permute` it, not reshape it, I assume.

Comment: @AnderBiguri or `shiftdim`

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mistaking the thing you want to do "change the shape" with the function name, `reshape`. What you want is to change the order of the dimensions, keeping the shape.

```
data_reshaped = permute(data,[3 2 1]);
```

Is probably the solution you seek, else try

```
data_reshaped = permute(data,[3 1 2]);
```